# How do I properly pass taxonomy term from panels to the context filter in views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I have a **Book Listing** content type and a **Series** content type. Both of these have a **Book Series** taxonomy term applied to them. What I want to do is override the **Series** page with panels and embed a view that will list every book with a matching **Book Series** tag.

What I've tried is creating a content pane view with a contextual filter of "Content: Book Series", Argument input set to "From context", and Required Context set to "Book Series". 
I've inserted the view and set the argument to the only one available: "Node being viewed". 
I've tried everything I could think of including creating contexts and relationships in the panel, creating relationships in the view, etc. I'm at my wit's end here. At the moment I'm relying on a separate view page to show what I want, but it's making the site navigation a pain to deal with. What am I doing wrong here and where can I find a good explanation of contexts?

Comment: I had a similar problem a month or so back and had to postpone solving it.  To get the answers I need, I have volunteered to provide documentation for the panels module team and have started getting some answers, although I have not yet gotten the solution to out mutual problem.  I can share what I know so far and keep you posted as I work towards the solution.

Comment: First, I assume you are using Drupal 7.10 and the latest version of Panels, views and Ctools.  Note that the latest rcl in Ctools is nearly six months old, where all the refinements are occurring in the dev version.  You may need to install the dev version.

Comment: Have you created a custom page panel or are you using one of the default panels provided by Panels to create your variant? (If so, which one?) Could you provide the settings you have for the Page Panel context and the variant context (there are two contexts settings involved and I do not yet know for sure how they relate to each other. ?

Comment: I'm using the Node Template. There are no visible settings for the Page Panel Context. Currently I have made no changes to the Variant Context. The Variant Context Summary lists to following:

Comment: ![context image](http://tsaot.com/sites/default/files/spp-context-summary.png) (image due to length) The item I'm interested in is %node:field_series_tag --> Book Series

Comment: I am indeed interested in what you have and continue to find out. In regards to using the dev snapshot, how confident are you in its stability? I need this site to go live within the next week.

Comment: You mentioned you have a separate view page that shows what you want.  Given your time frame, have you considered putting that in a block on the page instead of using panels?

Answer (score 4):

it depends how you are trying to get the taxonomy term, but here is one solution. In my example I'm using a node as my context, and a taxonomy field of that node as the contextual argument.

There are basically two things you need to get this to work. One, you need to use view panes, so you can get the arguments from the panels context.

[How can I show a view in panel with argument in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/how-can-i-show-a-view-in-panel-with-argument-in-drupal-7/18881#18881)

Second, if your trying to get the taxonomy term from a field you need to convert the term to a term id using validation.

[Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)

For instance this would work if you were trying to create a panel that diplayed a node, and a view of content related by a certain taxonomy term that that node belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do something similar with View Panes and Panelizer and was pretty confused for awhile.

1. Go to "Argument Input" and turn that to "No argument". You don't use Panels contexts for any of the next steps and supplying an argument (Such as a Panels context) will override the default value provided by the contextual filter.
2. Click you contextual filter, select "Provide default value", Type: "Taxonomy term from URL", all of the next three checkboxes, and then select your "Series" taxonomy. The rest is good.
3. Save it and continue wondering why Panels contexts exist.

Comment: Point 3 - for getting stuff from civi