# Show View Pane in Node Template based on Taxonomy Term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I am trying to add a view pane to a node template. The node and the content type shown in the view panel both have a taxonomy term field, so it should be a simple matter to link them, but I can't figure it out.

My node template has the relationship  Taxonomy term from Node. The view pane has context "has taxonomy term id" and has Argument Input from context. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what combination of selections I need to make in context and argument input to make it all work.

Under Argument Input, do I pick the field that contains the term or do I pick one of the choices under Taxonomy Terms?

Under Context filter value type, do I pick Term Name, Term from ID or something else (or nothing at all)?

I think I've tried all possible combinations, but I have the view showing up on nodes whether they contain the context or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Drupal 7.37, Panels 7.x-3.5 and Views 7.x-3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out!

To show a view in a panel where the view and panel are related by a taxonomy term (in my case Team Term (field_team_term), do the following:

1. Use the view content panes module to create a view content pane ([How can I show a view in panel with argument in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18881/5897)).
2. In the view content pane use contextual filter "Has Taxonomy Term ID". When Filter Value is not available: Hide View. When Filter Value is available - specify validation criteria - choose taxonomy vocabulary - Filter Value Type: Term Name converted to Term ID. (Some writers suggested checking the "Allow Multiple Values" box at the bottom of the window under More; I found that unnecessary.)
3. In the Pane Settings - Argument Input, select "From Context".
4. Under Required Context, select Name under Taxonomy Term.

That completes the views setup.

In the panel settings,

1. Set up a relationship"Taxonomy term from Node (on Node: Team Term [field_team_term])" in the case of my taxonomy term field.
2. In content, add the view pane, and select the taxonomy term relationship as the argument.

As near as I can tell, that is only combination of panel context and view arguments that will get the job done. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad you figured it out your own way. In Views still don't see the Pane Settings that you speak of. You mention "create a view content pane" I just create a regular view of unformatted list and fields that shows content.

Comment: To create a views content pane, you need to turn on Views Content Panes (views_content) in the chaos tools suite. See link in my answer, above.