# Set a views path to base URL

Tags: 7, views, uri

I am using view.

Every view needs path and i want to set that path to my base url.

For example i want to make a view which will take a Car as a argument and show result at

```
www.example.com/Car
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `contextual filters`.

You should add a `contextual filter` to your view and set the path to `%`. 
What kind of filter you should use depends on if `Car` a taxonomy term or a node and so on.

In the following example I have set my path to `stores/%` and a `store` is a node with a associated taxonomy term. I can display stores marked with a specific term by going to `http://example.com/stores/england` or `http://example.com/stores/sweden`.

- You find the `contextual filters` under the `advanced tab`.

[image: Contextual Filters]

- Here are the settings for the filter. Arguments from the url will be transformed into `Term ID`.

[image: Contextual Filter Settings]

*** EDIT *** Perhaps this link will help you [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)

Comment: Yah I already set this but in this case what will be the path of my view? It needs some path and if I give a path value to view then my path will be www.example.com/view-path/Car

Comment: In that case your views path should be `view-path/%`

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Krister Andersson's answer...

When creating a view, and defining its path keep in mind that the path you are defining is basically the name of the path.  IF you have a % in the path then th view has multiple names. If you define its path as cars/%, for instance, the view is called for any combination of path components in the % segment.  If you had a view with the  path /% it would basically be called for all URLS. This does not work for Drupal so wildcards are not used in the first position.