# Panels Node template with additional arguments

Tags: panels, views

The basic crux of what I'm trying to achieve is this:

When viewing a node - Content Type A (which is currently overridden with a panels node template) I want to be able to show a views block that will display the fields from one node of content type B.

To control which node from Content Type B would display on Content Type A pages, the idea was to set up a views pane with a contextual filter, so that any two nodes from hte two content types could be displayed together. This works fine by itself and in the preview.

But, I am having trouble getting panels to comply with my wishes!

I can set up a node template panel, but can't work out how to pass the second argument to the view pane. And I have tried to create a new panel to override the node so that I can pass the argument to the pane but it isn't overriding the node.

Any ideas how I can do this please?!

Comment: are you using D7 and Views and Panels 3?

Comment: Apologies, yes d 7.10 views 7.x-3.0 panels 7.x-3.x-dev

Comment: I have the same problem, but i am using drupal 6. I just want to pass additional parameters from the node tempalate to the view. I cant find it (if there is any). What can i do?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72999/passing-argument-from-url-in-panel-to-view-pane-or-block-d7

Answer (score 1):

You need a few components to make this work properly.

1. You View must have a display of type "Content pane".
2. A contextual filter.
3. In the Pane settings you should set your argument input to be "From context", and then picking an argument source that matches what your contextual filter wants. Most likely that will be a node id. (The argument setting could be a specific argument, first, second or so, as well, but that's generally not a very good idea)
4. Add the View *pane* to your panel page, *not the View* itself. If the Pane doesn't show up in the listing, your Pane settings are wrong.
5. Done.

Answer (score 0):

To pass URL argument from Panel to Content pane, try:

1. Add Contextual filter to the View.
   E.g.: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)
2. Change settings in 'View -> Pane settings -> Argument input' to load the argument 'From panel argument' (e.g. First). Try other options for your needs.