# Using Panels - Node Template.. How do i pass additional arguments for my blocks?

Tags: panels, views

I have content types: Project, News, and Country.

I have a node template that displays details of a **Project**. This node template displays a view, which displays all the **News**. I want to filter all the news by the project's **Country**.

**Project** has a cck field: country_id. How do i pass it's value to my News view?

---

tl;dr: using a panel node-template, how do i use the node's cck field as argument?

Comment: Welcome to d.se :) I'm wondering how this is different from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20486/panels-node-template-with-additional-arguments/ where you also posted? I have posted step by step instructions, and they should be relevant for your question as well.

Comment: So I think the critical piece of information here is number one in my answer in the linked to question. You must have a "content pane", not a "block".

Comment: hi thanks! i just finished updating my question after trying your solution. im still lost.

Comment: I used content pane when I tried it. I added an argument, then went to pane settings and changed argument input to From Context.. but i cant seem to find a way to choose my country_id there..

Comment: Let's take a step back. Excluding Panels from the equation all together, can you make the View create the list that you want? It sounds like the problem here is really in the contextual filters in the View?

Comment: well, the content pane displays all the countries. but when i try to enter a country id on the preview, nothing is displayed

Comment: I think you should start with a Views related question then. :) The _only_ things Panels will do in this context is put the number in the equivalent of the preview. The remaining 99% of the work is done by Views. You need to ensure the View can do what you want first. :)

Comment: lol i just realized i was trying to preview a country_id that does not have any news on it. so, yeah the view works the way i want it

Comment: Projects have a field country_id. how do i pass it to my view that displays all the news? i know i can just code it through a module hook. but i just would like to know if it is possible and how.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You should probably open a new question and start there. :)

Comment: @Letharion Maybe you can help me understanding something: Basing on the last comment from the OP, does the question still need to be answered?

Comment: I believe the answer is no. I think the OP needs create a View that will fulfill his requirements, and then this will be a dup to the linked to question, and my answer there should make sense. :)

Comment: thanks letharion, i edited my question (im not sure if you have seen it yet)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use content pane for the view to make it accept arguments.

Then when you insert the content pane, you should be able to use the node and all fields on the node using a token system to pass any variable to the view pane. How you setup the content pane determines which types of variables it will accept.