# Drupal 7.12: cloning default taxonomy with depth view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

i have two content types both with options for tags but using different vocabularies. I have cloned the default taxonomy view and created two separate views for both content type because one displays teasers and another uses a grid display. I also selected the relevant content type in the filter section.

When i selected the relevant vocabularies under contextual filters, both views worked. however, a few hours after doing this i started getting 'page not found' messages when i clicked on the tags (for both views). When i went to check whether the relevant vocabularies were still selected in the contextual filters, the views would show the option to choose a vocabulary. I then tried this method - [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name). this worked when i changed one view but stopped working when i changed the second view.

Question is, do i need to change the path for both views from the default /taxonomy/term/% or is there a setting i have missed or module i have to download? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think yes, in this case you need to change the taxonomy term path. [Here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/93722/16739) you can have a look how I solved the similar issue. Not sure if it's the only way to achieve it, but works!