# Views: How can I show a list of users who have a taxonomy term attached via a term reference field?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using the views module's built-in "Taxonomy term" view which overrides the way Drupal displays taxonomy by default and makes it accessible to views.  However, this only works for content, not users.

I tried creating a new view that lists users but there is no contextual filter like "User: has taxonomy term", just "Content: has taxonomy term."  In my case, however, some of the fields I want to display are term references stored on the user profile; they don't exist on any content.

Ideally, this is what I want: if a user visits the page taxonomy/term/oranges, it will show all users who have "oranges" in a taxonomy reference field.  How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you'll have to use a Relationship in your View. If your user has the field, it will appear in the list.

Comment: I have already configured a relationship (Content: Author).  However, though this makes the taxonomy term available under Fields, I am trying to show the users that have been "tagged" with the taxonomy term based on the term ID (The "Taxonomy Term" view shows all content that has been tagged with a term; I want to do the same for users.)  Adding a relationship alone does not allow me to do this.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do what you want, at my great surprise. [This](http://drupal.org/node/562270) thread, though, contains some snippets which should do the job.

Comment: This works a little better: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing this by overriding the taxonomy page with [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) instead of views.  I then made the old view taxonomy term override into a content pane.  Then, to get the "User: has taxonomy term" effect, I made a view (content pane) for each vocabulary with a "Term ID" contextual filter (supplied as a panel argument) and a relationship of "Taxonomy term: User using MY TERM".  I then added these views as content panes to the taxonomy override in panels.

I had to do this for each vocabulary, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution by using [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).

In my case, I have a dentistry website that has a taxonomy vocabulary named as "Expertise" and terms named as "Endodontics‎, Pedodontology‎" etc.

Dentist members can choose their area of expertises from this vocabulary on their profile2 pages ("Field: Expertise" as a term referenced field, profile2 is not neccessary at all).

I was trying to show term related dentists on taxonomy term archive pages. So I did this:

1. I created a Profiles block View that displays fields (You can create Users block if you don't use Profile2)
2. Added a Relationship -> Profile:Expertise
3. Added a Contexual filter -> (term from field_expertise) Taxonomy term: Term ID
4. Added an EVA Field
5. Selected Entity Type: Taxonomy Term
6. Selected Budles: Expertise
7. Selected Arguments: id
8. Set up EVA field "Visible" from "Expertise" vocabulary display (admin/structure/taxonomy/EXPERTISE/display