# Assigning User's In Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Views: How can I show a list of users who have a taxonomy term attached via a term reference field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/views-how-can-i-show-a-list-of-users-who-have-a-taxonomy-term-attached-via-a-te)

i want to assign users profile in taxonomy terms. So, i have created a vocabulary like `Gender` which has two terms like `Male` and `Female`. So, while registering an account in my website people need to choose his/her gender, and i wish if other people click on those terms from some one profile page, for example if they click on `Male` then on the taxonomy page all profiles with `Male` will get appear and same for other terms. But i see no result on those terms pages, to find a solution i have created a `Views` which successfully show users profile for each terms.
Now, my question is how to integrate the `Views` for the terms pages? 
|OR|
 On user profiles how to link `Terms` pages to those `Views` page?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the taxonomy term view lists **content (nodes)** and not **users**. If you want to use a new view on the default term page path, **taxonomy/term/%**, you have to **disable** the default view, create a new one, and give it that path. But it will also be in use for your others taxonomy terms pages !

So my advice is to **disable and ignore** this view, give a path to your full working new view, and set your **term path pattern** for this vocabulary the adress of your new view's page.

More simply :

1. Make a new view of users, set a "page" display and set it like this : /mypath/%
2. Add a taxonomy term ID argument
3. Add your fields
4. Go to your pattern url alias setting page, and for your vocabulary "gender", set terms URL to /mypath/% .

Now, all gender terms on your site will be linked to that view.

Comment: the idea was great but it returns "There is currently no content classified with this term." on that views page after editing the term url!

Comment: 1. Is your view a view of **users** ?
2. Is your pattern **yourviewpagepath/[term:tid]** ?
3. Is your view's argument your term reference field ?

Comment: Yes, its a view of users. Should i put yourviewpagepath/[term:tid] in views path? sorry, i can't understand number 3.. learning drupal `:)`..Thanks

Comment: You created a view that works for users, as you said. Give that view a display "page", and that page a "path", ending with "/%" . Now in your URL pattern admin section, paste that path in the term of that vocabulary.

Comment: i got that .. so, the term page url is `gender/male` so i should put it in views URL pattern? but that case it  do not works

Comment: Ok, so your view's page has gender/% path, and in your url pattern admin page (/admin/config/search/path/patterns) , set gender/[term:tid] as your gender terms' path.

Comment: what should be the `term:tid`? Sorry for the dump question `:)`

Comment: no no put it like that, it's a **token** saying that from now on, all the terms of that vocabulary will have the path gender/theirtermid, like gender/1 or gender/2 .

Comment: Do you use Panels ?

Comment: i dont know why same thing happens.. pls see it in action here > http://www.bangladesheveryday.com/occasional-photographer/5

Comment: I understand that you have 2 vocabularies : photographer-type and photographer-district. In your URL patterns page, you have to set those terms paths to photographer-type/[term:tid] and photographer-district/[term:tid] . Then in your view, your page display has path photographer-type/%. Then your terms will be accessible on the path photographer-district/5 for example.

I can't do more precise. If you want your terms to have their name in their path, you'll have to use Panels.