# How to make a taxonomy term display a field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I set up a taxonomy vocabulary (College attended) to be a field in my profile 2 registration form.

When a new user registers, he selects one of the terms of the vocabulary (i.e colleges).

I would like to have the surname of the users (a field in the core registration form) who went to a particular college displayed when a term is selected.

Please how do I achieve this.
P.S.: Presently I get only the notice "There is currently no content classified with this term", when i select a term.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view which shows surname of person given a username. Use https://drupal.org/project/viewfield and add it as field in the taxonomy and it should show surname.

By default linked users are not listed under taxonomy terms (read here : [Assigning User's In Taxonomy Terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59041/assigning-users-in-taxonomy-terms)) and there is another useful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524357/how-to-link-a-user-with-taxonomy-terms