# Match user based on multiple taxonomy field with Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I'm trying to make a view that "match" users depending on what they look for and what they offer.

When a new user register, he chooses what he wants to learn.

Let's say he chooses the following:

1) **Vocabulary:** "*language*" -> **Term:** "*French*"
2) **Vocabulary:** "*language*" -> **Term:** "*Spanish*"
3) **Vocabulary:** "*science*"  -> **Term:** "*Chemistry*"

Then, he chooses what he can offer in exchange:

1) **Vocabulary:** "*language*" -> **Term:** "*English*"
2) **Vocabulary:** "*science*"  -> **Term:** "*Physics*"

On another page, I want to display in a view all the users that "Match" his criteria.
Here, it could be :

- **User1:** Look for "*English*" and offer "*Spanish*"
- **User2:** Look for "*Physics*" and offer "*Chemistry*" and "*French*"

I can't figure a way to display all user that has the same taxonomy term as the user who did the research but with the learn / offer parts inversed. I hope this is clear.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you got as far as making a view with exposed filters to allow browsing of people offering different languages?

Comment: I haven't tried yet since I have the problem mentioned here, but I assumed you can do it as explained [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/views-how-can-i-show-a-list-of-users-who-have-a-taxonomy-term-attached-via-a-te)