# How to have contextual filters in views accept words instead of ID numbers?

Tags: 7, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal 7 views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)

I'm using Drupal 7, and what I want is to have my views use a contextual filter, so that if a view is located at mydrupalsite.com/myview I want to be able to go to mydrupalsite.com/myview/topicname and have the view use the topicname to filter the content.  Topicname in this case is a taxonomy item.

I've followed some tutorials and looked at articles about how to create contextual filters.  But the problem I have is that right now the contextual filter does not pick up the topicname in the URL.  The filter does work if I provide the ID number of the taxonomy item, so mydrupalsite.com/myview/93 will work (if 93 is the ID number of the taxonomy item).

How can I get the view to work so that the contextual filter reads the topicname?

Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, thank you pointing me to that.  That solution worked!