# Problem with Views / Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

**What I have**

1. A list of taxonomy terms with a name field, a logo field and a category field (category is defined as a list).
2. A View that should show all logos of the taxonomy term if a certain category matches (e.g. I want to show all Cloth logos if the category is Cloth).

**My problem:**

I'm trying to use a contextual filter to choose the taxonomy term category and provide a default value from the URL. But the URL contains "cloth" and not "1" so I get no results.

How can I convert the string to the value? Is that even possible?

Comment: Answered in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name

Comment: I'm not sure @Mołot : this thread answers for taxonomy term name, whereas here it's a list field key / value matter, imho.

Comment: Maybe we need clarification, @Gregor
As I read it, the core of a problem is **URL contains "cloth" and not "1"** just as in linked question. The part about what is going to be displayed seemed irrelevant, actually. Converting string to value, the very question's question, is done using `Specify validation criteria` just like answered in linked question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! @Gregor is right, it is a field key / value matter. I don't want to get the termname (or ID), but a custom field of the term (which is defines as a list, see above). And the URL contains only the string... how can I match those two?