# Panels "Page not found" when using required wildcard argument

Tags: 7, panels, views

I have a Panel Page, which displays several View Panes.  I have specified a term name as an argument in the path settings. This is used to filter the View Panes.

When I use an optional argument everything works fine - `clinical-role/!role_name`.  But when I change to a required argument `clinical-role/%role_name` then I get page not found when visiting `/clinical-role` and when visiting `/clinical-role/early-skills-for-non-training-grade-doctors`

I need the argument to be required because I don't want the panel to display when people visit `/clinical-role`.

Here is an export of the Panel Page: http://pastebin.com/ASmFnVU5

Here are my argument settings:

[image]
[image]

And also my context settings:

[image]

Comment: You could try having an optional argument and then in the selection rules add something like "taxonomy term is not empty"

Comment: Are you absolutely _sure_ that things work correctly if the argument is optional? It's not just that the panes happen to be working anyway? I can't think of a reason it would stop working because an argument changed from optional to required, as long as the argument was there in the first place.

Try creating a blank text pane and output the argument token in it for debugging, I would expect this to fail even when the argument is conditional, which points to something being wrong in the argument setup.

@PontusNilsson's suggestion sounds like a nice workaround though. :)

Comment: You're right, I added the term name to a text pane and nothing appears!  I've added my argument and context settings to the question, do they seem correct?  I'm quite new to panels ...

Comment: I think the problem is that my term has a hyphen in it - "Early skills for non-training grade doctors".  When I use a term that has no hyphen then the term name appears in my text pane. Must be related to the "transform dashes" option in views.

Comment: Yep - https://www.drupal.org/node/672606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my taxonomy terms had dashes, e.g. `"Early skills for non-training grade doctors"`.  When used in conjunction with views contextual filters and the option to `"Transform spaces to dashes in URL"`, it doesn't match properly, so no value for the context is provided.  This is related to the following views bug - https://www.drupal.org/node/672606 (no solution as yet for panels but there is a solution if you're just using a view page in comment #16).  My solution was to remove all dashes from my term names.  Not ideal but fixes the problem.

**Here is how I set things up to pull a taxonomy term name contextual filter into a View Pane**, in case it helps someone.  If anyone knows a better way to go about this then please let me know and I will update this answer:

### View Setup - Contextual Filter

[image: Contextual Filter:]

[image]

### View Setup - Argument Input

This part is counter intuitive, you have to choose "No argument input".  Providing a context from panels will prevent the default filter value from being used.  Thanks to the following comment for helping me figure this out: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name#comment59762_9339)

[image]

[image]

### Panel Setup

N.b you have to use a panel page here (structure > pages), so that you can make use of the wildcard feature.  I tried this by panelizing a node initially but couldn't get it to work.

Basic settings:

[image]

Argument settings:

[image]
[image]