# how to filter blog posts by taxonomy and by year

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, nodes

I have been trying to build a filter fuctionality for blog posts. I would want to filter by taxonomy terms and by the year the post was published. So basically in the content I want to list all blog posts – on sidebar I would have all used taxonomy terms listed and also a list of all years/months when post have been published.

Additionally I want the filter to be reflected by the URL structure:

- For a URL like  `domain.com/blog/2014` all posts from 2014 would be listed.
- For a URL like `domain.com/blog/cars` only posts tagged with 'car' would be listed.

Is there a module to do this – or should this be done with views? I have been trying to do this with views now but with not much luck. Especially with the url I don't understand how i can do that. Or if there is some tutorials on somewhere – that would help also.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Views is good way to solve this with Contextual Filters. You need to create a page view with the path **blog**. That will create a page **example.com/blog** that shows all blog posts.

Adding a `Content: Created year` contextual filter will set up a filter rule so that **example.com/blog/XXXX** filter the view by posts created on year **XXXX**.

For your last need, tag filtering, you're going to need to add another page view since a page view can't do a mixed contextual filtering; views doesn't know how to treat **XXXX** in **example.com/blog/XXXX** as both a year or tag.

See this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9339/45675) on how to set up a filter `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` filter that will you create something like **example.com/tags/YYYY** where **YYYY** is the name of your tag.

Comment: Thanks! But does this mean that I would need to have to different blog listing pages? example.com/blog where the yearly archive is and then example.com/blog-2 where the tag filtering is? This doesn't sound nice. On Wordpress this wouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: To the end user, the result would look the same if you set it up right. I'd argue that most users don't even bother looking at the URL bar unless they're having to manually go to another address.

Comment: Wordpress is blogging software right out the box. It's fantastic for that. Drupal is more of an abstract CMS application. The flexible/extendable of Drupal comes at the cost of simplicity. If you're looking for out-of-the-box blogging with Drupal, you should checkout [Drupal distributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution) that might your needs.