# Query URL containing term name instead of term ID on Views Exposed Filters

Tags: views, uri

I've got a View with an Exposed Filter that shows Taxonomy Terms that are used to filter the content that's going to be displayed as the result.

It's a View that shows recipes based on the filters chosen by the user (Type of Recipe, Type of Meat).

When I submit the form, I get the following URL:

```
/recipes-view?type-of-recipe=all&type-of-meat=22
```

The last parameter shows the number 22, which is the Term ID for the value chosen. The URL has to contain the Term Name instead of the Term ID.

Can I change it via `hook_views_query_alter()` or is it needed to create a custom handler for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name **just follow the above link and check.**

Comment: @Sidharth your comment is linking to QA on contextual filters, OP is trying to change a Exposed Filter Query string

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to do this in code. You basically need to:

1. Add relationship to taxonomy term via entity reference field (it would probably also work with term reference)
2. Add exposed filter using this relationship (search for field Taxonomy Term: Term)

It works fine and you get URL, such as:

```
recipes-view?tid=vejuu
```

If you want to have an URL key `type-of-meat`, you can set it in *More* drop-down in you exposed filter configuration. The field name is *Filter Identifier*

I experienced problems with using features trying to prevent duplicates created by joining taxonomy terms.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to add the taxonomy term via entity reference field?