# Change url arguments from tid to terms name at exposed filter

Tags: views

I am using a views exposed filter for taxonomy terms for my node view page with auto-submit.
when I apply the filter at url I am getting a url **localhost/test/list?term=66**
instead of which I want it to be '**?term=[term_name]'**.
I have added taxonomy term as relation at the filter.

Note: I have better-exposed-filter module enabled and I am not using contextual filter.

I followed this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161448/query-url-containing-term-name-instead-of-term-id-on-views-exposed-filters) posted before, but not able to see the term name instead of term id