# Term name converted to term id filter removed?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I am currently working on a view that should show all items from a content type with the given taxonomy term **name** (not id) in the url.

While this was easy to achieve in D7 (by following the answer on this question: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)), I can't seem to find the validator filter now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predefined view "taxonomy term" might have the answer.
It will always show results based on the TID. 
I believe that if you just add an alias to your URL, it will work just fine. You can use the module pathauto to automatically create an alias.

Comment: Note that pathauto can only generate aliases for the default path (/taxonomy/term/TID). You can easily change the view, but if you need different views for different vocabularies, then you either need something like Page Manager, that allows you to have different displays with different views (which then in turn needs a core patch to pass that TID to a views block again). or you use your own path and have custom code to generate aliases for that.