# Link a Page to another Page using Views and taxonomy

Tags: views

I have a Page created using a View using a Content Type called Sectors, which displays rows of images with a title underneath the image. The Sector content type has the fields - Title, Image, Sector Category (uses a Taxonomy). A Sector can have many Projects.... so.....

When the user clicks on the Sector Image or Title, i want my site to go to another Page which is created using a View and display all the Projects belonging to that Sector using the Sector Category field (which is a field on both Sector and Projects content type, passed to it from the previous Sectors page), to select all the Projects that are held in the Projects Content Typle - which has fields Title, Image, Sector Category.

How can I link the 2 views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create your other page, using Views, with a path pattern similar to the following:

```
projects_by_sector/%tid
```

This page can then be configured to display only content of type Projects and the fields you need (Title, Image, Sector Category, etc). Most importantly, you need to configure a contextual filter with the following configuration:

- For the "Content: Sector Category" field
- "Provide default value"
- "Raw value from URL"
- "Path component" => 2 (this follows from the example URL above)

Now back in your existing Views page for the Sectors list, you need to do some field rewriting. This can be done in a number of ways, the easiest would be to add the Sectors Taxonomy reference again as a field and do the rewriting on that field. You can do these using the following steps:

- Add the "Content: Sector Category" field
- Save with the default configuration
- Rearrange your fields and move the new field below/after the "Content: Title" field. This is important so that the replacements token ***[title]*** will be available for the rewriting.
- Hide the "Content: Title" field by selecting "Exclude from Display" on its configuration
- Configure the new "Content: Sector Category" field
- Select "Plain text" as "Formatter"
- Expand "Rewrite Results"
- Select "Rewrite the output of this field"
- Enter the following in the "Text" textarea to use the title of your sector
  ***[title]***
- Select "Output this field as a link"
- Enter the following as the "Link path"
  ***projects_by_sector/[field_sector_category-tid]***

This is a rough idea, you need to tune your views page accordingly, but the end-result should be what you asked for. Hope this helps!

Comment: In my Sector List View, I have 3 fields selected  - Sector Image, Title, and now I have Sector Category. I have set Sector Category so that it Excludes from Display ticked, Output this Field as a Link ticked, Link Path set as projects-by-sector/[field_sector_category-tid] . I have also changed the settings for the Sector Image and Title so they do nothing (i.e. don't link to Content). On my site, now when I hover over a Sector  image to click and select one, it does nothing.

Comment: I read your question again, it seems that you want to use the Sector's Title or the Sector's Image as the link to the Sector's projects list. I suggested an additional field for that. Is that an option for you? Otherwise, I will update my answer accordingly and specifically for using the Sector's Image as a link.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Sectors Title or Image to link to the Projects View using the Sector Category . thanks

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: when Im configuring the Projects by Sector View, I have added a Contextual Filter for Sector Project Category as specified above, Default Value ticked , Raw value from URL ticked, Path Component = 2. This results in nothing being displayed in the Preview at the bottom of the view. If I select  "Display all results for the specified field " then all the projects appear.  Is it because Sector Project Category is a taxonomy term and needs different configuration?

Comment: I found a solution to my contextual filter with taxonomy problem here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name    I have the Projects Views working now, and will now look at the Sectors View

Comment: The preview should work as long as you type in a valid taxonomy term id (for Sector Category terms) in the "Preview with contextual filters" text box.

Comment: Fantastic! Good luck with your project!