# How to use Php code in Views page contextual filter with dynamic URL i.e using %?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type *App* with a term reference field called *App category*.

I'm creating a view page with path **app/%**. I don't want to use App ID or anything numeric in URL in place of **%**, so I'll be using **app/cooking-app** where **cooking-app** is URL Alias of *App Category*.

How can I display all the nodes whose value in *App Category* field is **cooking-app**? I can easily do this using PHP code but PHP code in contextual filters is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly recommend not using PHP code to do this; tying PHP code to configuration can be error-prone and it won't exist in Drupal 8's Views.

Rather, you can use the solution in [Drupal 7 views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name?rq=1) where you can use the **Validator**, *Taxonomy Term*, instead of *PHP Code*, with the *Term name converted to Term ID* filter.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, The solution on the link provided worked like a charm. Thanks.