# How to change taxonomy term ID to term name?

Tags: 8, views

I'm trying to change path of my site which is based on taxonomy tags. Default path of my site in this context is `/taxonomy/term/120` (or other number - TID).

In Drupal 7 option to change TID to term:name was easy using **Contextual filter** and **Filter value type** set to **Term name coverted to Term ID** (shown eg here: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)).

The big problem I'm struggling with is that there is no **Filter value type** field (dropdown menu) in Drupal 8. This is picture of my screen:
[image]
So I **cannot change TID to term name**.

Have anyone idea how I can exchange them. Is there another way to change them in Drupal 8?

Comment: Cant you use the term name itself as the filter? Without converting it to a term id first?

Comment: You are right, but if you have space in your taxonomy and you want convert this space into dash look this patch (#14). https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2710407

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create a relation with the taxonomy terms by adding the relationship with the taxonomy list or `Taxonomy terms on node`. Once you have added the relation, you can now add a contextual filter called `name` with the category `Taxonomy term`. This way you can pass the taxonomy term by name to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a relationship to taxonomy term: field will do just about the same thing as taxonomy term: on node